# Convert .a file to .dll

Tags: c++, c, windows, unix, tar

This question is surely answered here somewhere, but I couldn't find it. I've been writing Java for over a decade now and my C experience was on Unix, so I'm kinda at square one here. In my Unix experience, someone else wrote the makefile and it just worked.

I have downloaded the C source code for libtar-1.2.11 from feep and ran `make` on it from inside of cygwin. This created a `.a` file and a `.exe` file. The EXE file appears to essentially be tar to run on Windows, but what I wanted was for the libraries to read and process the file in my own code.

If I remember correctly, those should be in the `.a` file (archive??) and this needs to be linked into a library that I can use from my C++ program. So I'm looking for a way to do that.

I am writing a library that will use a `.tgz` file and so I want to use this library. I think I'd like to turn libtar into a DLL as well as create a DLL myself for use in other languages.

So, how do I turn my `.a` file into something usable by other apps, and how do I access it from inside my code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a mechanic to convert .a -> .dll. You can compile the source code on your windows machine to generate a .dll however.

Comment: You won't be working with the `.a` file to create a DLL, you'll work directly with the sources.

Comment: @MarkRansom is right, you'll need to recompile. `.a` files generally don't contain position-independent code (PIC), so you can't link with the contained code dynamically.

Comment: Except on Windows, they do, since the code is always position independent (-fPIC is redundant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generated `libmylib.a` is actually an archive of all `*.o` for `libtar-1.2.11`. 
you can verify this by doing `nm libmylib.a`, it will print all the `*.o` files.
Write your code, and link:

```
gcc -o my_application my_application.o -lmylib
```

You generated this with cygwin, you can't generate a dll out of that as far as i know.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a DLL is the equivalent of a *shared* library in Unix (a `.a` is a library for static linking, the Windows equivalent being a `.LIB` file), so you want to build a shared library.

Indeed, when you build as

`make LDFLAGS=-shared`

the resulting `libtar/libtar.exe` will actually be a misnamed DLL.

Note, however, that a cygwin-translated DLL is something different from a native Windows DLL and will always depend on Cygwin DLLs (and potentially even an installed Cygwin environment) to run, so if you plan on including it in native Windows code, this is probably not an approach you want to pursue.

May I suggest that you switch from the plenty dead (last release in 2003) libtar to libarchive, which comes with native [Windows build instructions](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/wiki/BuildInstructions#Windows/Visual_Studio)?